# What's the point of adding service to firewall rules in centos?

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, services

My purpose is to make firewall allow connections to my newly installed service/server/daemon on Centos.

I create `/etc/firewalld/services/myservice.xml` file, then reload firewall, then do:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=myservice
```

Which returns:

```
success
```

But I still can't see `myservice` port when scanning server's ports until I do:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=###/tcp
```

Where ### is default port for my service.

On the other hand I can add port without adding service, and my service will be accessible right away. Can somebody explain the purpose of setting up firewall services(in addition to ports) to me? (or alternatively (possibly) explain that I'm doing it wrong).

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing *service* in the Linux OS sense and in the networking sense. What you installed was an OS service, but what `firewall-cmd` requires is a network service.

The network service you require is the name assigned to a port number reserved for communication with the software which is implementing that service, eg a web host will listen on the HTTP service port 80, and any browser requiring access to the web host will communicate though this port on the machine where the web host is running.

To set up the firewall for HTTP on this machine you can use:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=http
```

In other words, you use the network service name, not the OS service name, which bears no relation. If the OS service you installed implements a standard network service, then you can use the network service name in `--add-service=`; if it's not a standard service, then you can use only the numeric `--add-port=` form.

You can find the network services that `firewall-cmd` recognises with:

```
firewall-cmd --list-services
```

More information on ports and services can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_%28computer_networking%29).